# Got error after deploying an " Google Data API" application in Windows Azure Application Emulator

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-worker-roles

Currently I am working on Google DATA Calendar and Contacts APIs. I have written an web application to access public calendar by Google Data APIs. It is working fine locally.

After I deployed this application in Azure Emulator, it stopped working saying

InnerException  {"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 209.85.231.104:443"}   System.Exception {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}

Code that is written :

```
            CalendarService oSrv = new CalendarService("GoogleAPIs_Cal_V1");
            EventQuery oQuery = new EventQuery();
            oQuery.Uri = new Uri(XXX);

            if (strUserName != null && strUserName.Length > 0)
            {
                oSrv.setUserCredentials(strUserName, strPwd);
            }

            oQuery.StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-11);
            oQuery.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

            EventFeed calFeed = oSrv.Query(oQuery) as EventFeed;

            ArrayList dates = new ArrayList(50);

            DataTable dtEvents = FillDataTable();

            while (calFeed != null && calFeed.Entries.Count > 0)
            {
                // look for the one with dinner time...
                foreach (Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry entry in calFeed.Entries)
                {
                    DataRow dtRow = dtEvents.NewRow();
                    dtRow["EventTitle"] = entry.Title.Text;
                  :
                  :
                }
             }
```

Can you please help me on this front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is resolved.
I tried by keeping webrole in HWC mode.
To use hwc, open csdef file. remove  section.

Please visit link
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/9fd8432e-ab14-44f6-823a-7e609c3ec655